# Is it possible to make an apple pay payment without the apple pay interface?

Tags: ios, swift, nfc, payment, applepay

Recently we shipped the app by suppressing apple pay when our app is in the foreground.
We suppressed apple pay by adding the necessary code (`requestAutomaticPassPresentationSuppression`) and adding `com.apple.developer.passkit.pass-presentation-suppression` in the entitlement.

But one of the customers reported they were able to pay in the terminal using apple pay without using the apple pay interface! while making the payment it didn't ask for the passcode or face-ID when the user is within our app!

When we test locally the `apple pay` is not triggering when we bring our app near POS terminal!

Is it possible to make an `apple pay` payment without the `apple pay interface`? Just wondering what might be settings used by customer? or is it possible to trigger `apple pay` without any apple interface in some POS terminals?

Comment: If an Apple Pay payment could be made without face ID or another credential, this would be a huge security bug. I would therefore recommend to clarify with the customer what really happened.